# Why didn't X-ray come greet Stanley and Hector at the end of "Holes"?

Tags: holes, louis-sachar

At the end of *Holes* when Stanley and Hector return to Camp Green Lake, they are greeted by everyone except X-ray.

> "Caveman? Is that you?"
>
> He turned to see Armpit and Squid coming out of the Wreck Room. Squid shouted back into the Wreck Room, "Caveman and Zero are out here!"
>
> Soon all the boys from Group D had gathered around him and Zero.
> "Good to see you, man," Armpit said, shaking his hand. "We thought you were buzzard food."
>
> "Stanley is being released today," said Mr. Pendanski.
>
> "Way to go," said Magnet, hitting him on the shoulder.
>
> "And you didn't even have to step on a rattlesnake," said Squid.
>
> Even Zigzag shook Stanley's hand. "Sorry about . . . you know."
>
> "It's cool," said Stanley.
>
> "We had to lift the truck clear out of the hole," Zigzag told him.
>
> "It took everybody in C, D, and E. We just picked it right up."
>
> "It was really cool," said Twitch.
>
> X-Ray was the only one who didn't come over. Stanley saw him hang back behind the others a moment, then return to the Wreck Room.

Why didn't he come and greet Stanley and Hector like everyone else did?